# Unable to apply catalog successfully on nodes due to running iexplore process

Tags: puppet

Puppet Version: 4.10.0
Puppet Server Version: 7.1
OS Name/Version: RHEL 7.1

Puppet Agent server: Windows 2012 R2

I am trying to run 6 puppet manifests on 50 Windows servers to install Citrix, ms-office, winbeat, filebeat, uipath, and configure some system registry keys, but every time I run "puppet agent -t" cmd on the nodes, after running configuration from a few of manifests, it is opening internet explorer and asking to kill iexplore processes (running as the background processes in task manager), even though I have not mentioned any such cmd/rule/line in manifests -

" Notice: /Stage[main]/Beats/Notify[Starting filebeat...]/message: Starting filebeat*...*

Notice: /Stage[main]/Beats/Notify[Starting filebeat...]/message: defined 'message' as 'Starting filebeat*...'*

Confirm All [N] No Are you sure you want to perform the Stop-Process operation on the following item: iexplore*(10192)? [Y] Yes [A] Yes to [L] No to All [S] Suspend [?] Help(default is "Y"): "*

and the catalog fails to apply successfully when it gets no response for the killing of iexplore proc. If iexplore is running in the 'Apps' tab in task manager (i.e. when I manually run iexplore in the foreground to test), while manifests are running, iexplore proc is killed by itself and then the catalog is applied successfully. If no iexplore proc is running, the catalog is applied successfully on nodes.

Can someone please help explain to me what is the reason for this automatic iexplore proc termination while running puppet manifest on agents and how can we prevent his from happening cos in background iexplore will always run on my nodes?

Tried to clear internet explorer cache and browsing history, checked for internet options.

Desired Behavior:

"Applied Catalog successfully"

Actual Behavior:

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform the Stop-Process operation on the following
item: iexplore(10192)?
[Y] Yes [A] Yes to All [N] No [L] No to All [S] Suspend [?] Help
(default is "Y"):Error: Command exceeded timeout
Error: /Stage[main]/Office/Exec[act]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Command exceeded timeout
Info: Stage[main]: Unscheduling all events on Stage[main]
Notice: Applied catalog in 315.64 seconds

Comment: Is your question asking why your `filebeat` service is attempting to interactively stop another process called `iexplore`? It is difficult to discern from the question, and we would need to see relevant code. Also, this may not be Puppet related.

Comment: To expand on @Matt's comment, to the best of my knowledge, the behavior you describe is not associated with Puppet itself.  It may be a facet of some particular third-party module you're using, or even of Puppet code you've written yourself, but I think it's even more likely that Matt has hit it on the head: the issue may well be an idiosyncrasy of one of the installer programs you are running via Puppet.  Whatever the source, the first step of solving or working around the problem is to characterize it more specifically. In other words, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I have not mentioned in manifest anywhere to kill iexplore process, still it is killing the proc as mentioned above, please help me resolve this problem, iexplore will keep running on the nodes in backgrpund, and I want to execute all the manifests in the nodes without killing iexplore.

Comment: class citrix{
$citrix_source = 'http://x.x.x.x:8081/nexus/content/repositories/infra-manager-repository/citrix-receiver/14.3.100/citrix-receiver-14.3.100.exe'
file{'C:\\temp\\citrix':
     ensure => directory,}->
download_file{ 'download_citrix':
                url => $citrix_source,
                destination_directory => 'C:\\temp\\citrix\\',}->

        exec{ 'citrix_installation':
                command => 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c C:\temp\citrix\citrix-receiver-14.3.100.exe /silent',
                creates => 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Citrix',
        }
}

Comment: For your reference, this is one of my manifests - citrix.pp